# Bounds for the orders of second largest subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb F_q)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classical-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$By Patton's thesis, except for a finite number of possibilities, the $(n-1, 1)$ parabolic subgroup, $P$ say, has the largest number of elements among all non-trivial subgroups of $\SL_n(\mathbb F_q)$. The index of $P$ in $\SL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ is $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\SL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ such that no conjugate of $H$ is contained in $P$. Is there a non-trivial upper bound for the number of elements of $H$?

Comment: I edited the title. If you want an upper bound of the size of $H$ under your assumption, then it will actually be assumed by a *maximal  subgroup*. The book *The Subgroup Structure of the Finite Classical Groups* by Kleidman and Liebeck discusses maximal subgroups of groups like $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb F_q)$. Yet it might be painful to derive an answer from that.

Comment: I would guess that at least for large enough $n$ it will be the stabilizer of a $2$-dimensional subspace with structure $q^{2(n-2)}:({\rm SL}(n-2,q) \times {\rm SL}(2,q)):(q-1)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's also my intuition, but do you know how one might prove it without going through Aschbacher's theorem?

Comment: @Ramin I can't imagine any easier alternative to Aschbacher's theorem. Of course that would take a certain amount of work, but if you really needed to prove it then that would be the way to go.

Comment: @DerekHolt The class $\mathcal C_G$ for $G = SL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ is very explicit in Aschbacher's paper, but it's not clear to me what Aschbacher's main theorem actually says about subgroups that are not in $\mathcal C_G$, so perhaps the description is in Kleidman and Liebeck as Peter Mueller suggested.

Comment: Yes, the book by Kleidman and Liebeck gives more precise information, which should enable you to prove the result you need. But they only deal with dimensions $n>12$. There is another book by Bray, Holt, and Roney-Dougal that lists all the maximal subgroups for $n \le 12$, so you would need that to resolve small values of $n$ and $q$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Your book is beautifully written! Thank you for recommending it!